# could not find deserializer for type error in ksoap2 android

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I want to send a class as parameter to a web service using ksoap2 in android.
This is my code in android :

```
public Object simpleConnect() {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, methodName);

    Foo para = new Foo();
    para.setFooId(2333222);
    para.setCompanyId(12);
    para.setField2(true);
    para.setField3(2);
    para.setPrimaryKey(765);
    para.setUserId(987);

    request.addProperty("param", para);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.addMapping(namespace, "Foo", Foo.class);

    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(url);
    try {
        ht.call(soapAction, envelope);

        return envelope.getResponse(); //got error deserialize in this line
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

and this is method in my service that I try to call it :

```
public Foo addObjFoo(Foo param) throws SystemException {

    System.out.println("something");

    fooPersistence.update(param, false);

    return param;
}
```

and this is my wsdl :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="urn:http.service.test.com" xmlns:intf="urn:http.service.test.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns1="http://model.test.com" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:http.service.test.com">
    <!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)-->
    <wsdl:types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://model.test.com">
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            <complexType name="FooSoap">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="companyId" type="xsd:long"/>
                    <element name="field2" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    <element name="field3" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <element name="fooId" type="xsd:long"/>
                    <element name="primaryKey" type="xsd:long"/>
                    <element name="userId" type="xsd:long"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="addFooResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="addFooReturn" type="xsd:int"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="printmessageRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="behi" type="xsd:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="addFooRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="para" type="xsd:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="printmessageResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="printmessageReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="addObjFooResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="addObjFooReturn" type="tns1:FooSoap"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="addObjFooRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="param" type="xsd:anyType"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="FooServiceSoap">
        <wsdl:operation name="addFoo" parameterOrder="para">
            <wsdl:input message="impl:addFooRequest" name="addFooRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="impl:addFooResponse" name="addFooResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="addObjFoo" parameterOrder="param">
            <wsdl:input message="impl:addObjFooRequest" name="addObjFooRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="impl:addObjFooResponse" name="addObjFooResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="printmessage" parameterOrder="behi">
            <wsdl:input message="impl:printmessageRequest" name="printmessageRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="impl:printmessageResponse" name="printmessageResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="Plugin_obtice_FooServiceSoapBinding" type="impl:FooServiceSoap">
        <wsdlsoap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="addFoo">
            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input name="addFooRequest">
                <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:http.service.test.com" use="encoded"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="addFooResponse">
                <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:http.service.test.com" use="encoded"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="addObjFoo">
            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input name="addObjFooRequest">
                <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:http.service.test.com" use="encoded"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="addObjFooResponse">
                <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:http.service.test.com" use="encoded"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="printmessage">
            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input name="printmessageRequest">
                <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:http.service.test.com" use="encoded"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="printmessageResponse">
                <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:http.service.test.com" use="encoded"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="FooServiceSoapService">
        <wsdl:port binding="impl:Plugin_obtice_FooServiceSoapBinding" name="Plugin_obtice_FooService">
            <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/WebService-portlet/axis/Plugin_obtice_FooService"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

and finally this is my Foo class in client side :

```
package com.obtice.liferaytest;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

public class Foo implements KvmSerializable {

    protected long localCompanyId;

    public long getCompanyId() {
        return localCompanyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(long param) {
        this.localCompanyId = param;
    }


    protected boolean localField2;

    public boolean getField2() {
        return localField2;
    }

    public void setField2(boolean param) {
        this.localField2 = param;
    }


    protected int localField3;

    public int getField3() {
        return localField3;
    }

    public void setField3(int param) {
        this.localField3 = param;
    }


    protected long localFooId;

    public long getFooId() {
        return localFooId;
    }

    public void setFooId(long param) {
        this.localFooId = param;
    }


    protected long localPrimaryKey;

    public long getPrimaryKey() {
        return localPrimaryKey;
    }

    public void setPrimaryKey(long param) {
        this.localPrimaryKey = param;
    }


    protected long localUserId;

    public long getUserId() {
        return localUserId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long param) {
        this.localUserId = param;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int index) {

        Object object = null;

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            object = localCompanyId;
            break;
        case 1:
            object = localField2;
            break;
        case 2:
            object = localField3;
            break;
        case 3:
            object = localFooId;
            break;
        case 4:
            object = localPrimaryKey;
            break;
        case 5:
            object = localUserId;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return object;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 9;
    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            info.name = "companyId" ;
            info.type = PropertyInfo.LONG_CLASS ;
            break;
        case 1:
            info.name = "field2";
            info.type = PropertyInfo.BOOLEAN_CLASS ;
            break;
        case 2:
            info.name = "field3";
            info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS ;
            break;
        case 3:
            info.name = "fooId";
            info.type = PropertyInfo.LONG_CLASS ;
            break;
        case 4:
            info.name = "primaryKey";
            info.type = PropertyInfo.LONG_CLASS ;
            break;
        case 5:
            info.name = "userId";
            info.type = PropertyInfo.LONG_CLASS ;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int index, Object obj) {
        String objStr = obj.toString();

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            localCompanyId = Long.parseLong(objStr);
            break;
        case 1:
            localField2 = Boolean.parseBoolean(objStr);
            break;
        case 2:
            localField3 = Integer.parseInt(objStr);
            break;
        case 3:
            localFooId = Long.parseLong(objStr);
            break;
        case 4:
            localPrimaryKey = Long.parseLong(objStr);
            break;
        case 5:
            localUserId = Long.parseLong(objStr);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error after calling web service and when taking response :

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soapenv:Server.userException' faultstring: 'org.xml.sax.SAXException: Deserializing parameter 'param':  could not find deserializer for type {urn:http.service.test.com/}Foo' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@4057bb40
```

Please help me. I completely stuck with it.

thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message and I was going crazy trying to figure it out.

Add this line before the transport call

```
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
```

and these two after the call

```
Log.i(REQUEST, androidHttpTransport.requestDump); 
Log.i(RESPONSE, androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
```

and see what the type is for Foo that you are sending in your envelope and make sure that it matches the type declared in your WSDL.

In my project, it turned out that the envelope mapping

```
envelope.addMapping(namespace, "GetFacilityReservations",GetFacilityReservations.class);
```

was sending my custom class as type n0 because that was the type of the namespace I had initially declared. But my class was of a different type.

So then all I needed to do was change namespace to in my mapping to the right one.

```
envelope.addMapping("urn:XPressLocate", "GetFacilityReservations",GetFacilityReservations.class);
```